# Using a 32 bit assembler

Tags: assembly, 32-bit

I am trying to assemble some 32-bit code as such

```
gcc -o a.out code.s
```

but I am getting the following message:

```
Error: invalid instruction suffix for 'push'
```

back from the assembler. The line of code that is causing this is the following:

```
    pushl   %ebp
```

I have done some research that says I need to use a 32-but assembler. Can someone show me how I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to do this on a 64 bit system, where gcc defaults to `-m64`.

So just do this:

```
gcc -Wall -m32 code.s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 32 bit assembly code, then you need to compile with a 32 bit toolset. It looks like you are compiling with a 64 bit toolset which would appear to be the problem. You cannot mix 32 bit and 64 bit code in one module.

Your options:

1. Compile with 32 bit tools, and emit 32 bit objects.
2. Port the assembly code to 64 bit.

Comment: Your original tags confused me. The fact that you tagged it 64 bit made me assume that you wanted a 64 bit output.